# Return Promise response from Async Thunk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, redux-toolkit, thunk

I have a an Axios promise being called from an asyncThunk. I am using the redux toolkit to capture the responses. However, I do not know of a way to return the actual response of the promise call to the "rejected" state of the slice. Here is my call:

```
export const registerThunk = createAsyncThunk("registerThunk", async (payload: TRegisterPayload) => {
  const axios_response = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/createNewUser", payload);
  return axios_response;
});
```

**How do I get access to the error response "data" member in inside my "Rejected" state?**

```
      builder.addCase(registerThunk.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.state = 3;
        state.text = "Error";
        state.buttonColor = "red";
        state.errorMessage = action.error.message as string;
      });
```

Normally, without the redux toolkit, I would do something like this to get the data:

```
  const axios_response = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/createNewUser", payload).catch((err :AxiosError)=>{
    err.response?.data;  **<--- I can read the error response here**
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

So after lots of research I have found an acceptable solution to my problem. I am posting it here for newcomers.

Basically, to return the response of the promise you have to use the two functions "rejectWithValue" and "fulfillWithValue" from the "ThunkAPI". Here is my updated asyncThunk:

```
export const registerThunk = createAsyncThunk("registerThunk", async (payload: TRegisterPayload, { rejectWithValue, fulfillWithValue }) => {
  try {
    const registerResponse = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/createNewUser", payload);
    return fulfillWithValue(registerResponse.data);
  } catch (e) {
    return rejectWithValue(e);
  }
});
```

And whenever the promise is rejected the "rejected" part of the "extraReducers" will trigger and the data can be found in the ***actions.payload.data*** member, like this:

```
      builder.addCase(registerThunk.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.state = 3;
        state.text = "Error";
        state.buttonColor = "red";
        // Keep type cast simple
        let typedPayload = action.payload as AxiosError<ServerErrorResponse>;
        state.errorMessage = ***typedPayload.response?.data***.serverError.code as string;
      });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your thunk in **try catch** block. Then send the error back to your slice.

Please check the code sample.

```js
export const registerThunk = createAsyncThunk("registerThunk", async (payload: TRegisterPayload, {
    rejectWithValue
}) => {
    try {
        const axios_response = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/createNewUser", payload);
        return axios_response;
    } catch (e) {
        return rejectWithValue(e);
    }
});
```

You can then access **data** in **rejected**.

Comment: Hi . Thanks for answering. Your tip paid off. I have made a complete example with the "fullfillWithValue" as well. I am going to post it as a solution.